# When snapping a window with shortcuts, Windows doesn't show what can be snapped next to it

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, windows-10-v1903, windows-snap-assist

The [<kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>left</kbd> | <kbd>right</kbd>] arrow shortcuts on Windows 10 snap the window to the left or right side of the screen and show small thumbnails of the other windows that you can snap next to it.

After updating Windows 10 to version 1903, the shortcuts do still snap the Windows but the thumbnails of the other windows are not displayed anymore, despite the option being enabled in Windows settings:

[image: Work with multiple windows]

What can I do to make the shortcuts work again as before the update?

Answer (score 3):

The default shortcut combination for snapping windows has slightly changed in version 1903:

- <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>left</kbd> | <kbd>right</kbd> = snap only
- <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>left</kbd><kbd>left</kbd> | <kbd>right</kbd><kbd>right</kbd> = snap and show the thumbnail of the other windows

Comment: This really saved!  I've been looking around on the same for sometime and finally landed here with an answer. I wonder why this has not been clearly documented in this official [Snap your windows](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/snap-your-windows-885a9b1e-a983-a3b1-16cd-c531795e6241) page especially the shortcut option to snap and show thumbnail of other windows.